# Trouble with using ZipInputStream.getNextEntry() multiple times

Tags: java, android, zip

I am trying to unzip specific files from a zip. I first get a `ZipInputStream`:

```
ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath)));
```

Alright, this works! Now I want to extract two files, called F1 and F2, so I call

```
extractFileFromZip(zipIn, Path + "F1", "F1")
extractFileFromZip(zipIn, Path + "F2", "F2")

public static boolean extractFileFromZip(ZipInputStream inZip, String file, String name) throws Exception {
    byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    boolean found = false;

    ZipEntry ze;
    while((ze = inZip.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        if(ze.getName().equals(name)) {
            found = true;
            // delete old file first
            File oldFile = new File(file);
            if(oldFile.exists()) {
                if(!oldFile.delete()) {
                    throw new Exception("Could not delete " + file);
                }
            }

            FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int count = 0;
            while((count = inZip.read(data)) != -1) {
                outFile.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            outFile.close();
            //inZip.closeEntry();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now the problem is with `inZip.getNextEntry()`. For F1 it will cycle through all the files correctly and then give `null`. But for F2, it will just give `null`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: maybe because after calling `extractFileFromZip` the first time, you've exhausted the input stream ...

Comment: How can it "give null" when the return type is `boolean`?

Comment: You should consider using the path api. It's a much more recent and streamlined api then the old file or zip. A File and ZipEntry are treated exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You're scanning the entire stream, consuming it. When you try to do it the second time, the stream is already at-end, so will do nothing.

Also, streaming all bytes in the zip file is slow, if you only want a small part of it.

Use a [`ZipFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) instead, since it allows random access to the zip entries, so it is faster, and it allows reading the entries in random order.

*Note: The code below has been changed to use Java 7+ features for better error handling, such as [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).*

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(filePath);
extractFileFromZip(zipFile, path + "F1", "F1");
extractFileFromZip(zipFile, path + "F2", "F2");

public static boolean extractFileFromZip(ZipFile zipFile, String file, String name) throws IOException {
    ZipEntry ze = zipFile.getEntry(name);
    if (ze == null)
        return false;
    Path path = Paths.get(file);
    Files.deleteIfExists(path);
    try (InputStream in = zipFile.getInputStream(ze)) {
        Files.copy(in, path);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Alternatively, stream it only once, then check for both names in the `while` loop.

```
Map<String, String> nameMap = new HashMap<>();
nameMap.put("F1", path + "F1");
nameMap.put("F2", path + "F2");
extractFilesFromZip(filePath, nameMap);

public static void extractFilesFromZip(String filePath, Map<String, String> nameMap) throws IOException {
    try (ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath)))) {
        for (ZipEntry ze; (ze = zipIn.getNextEntry()) != null; ) {
            String file = nameMap.get(ze.getName());
            if (file != null) {
                Path path = Paths.get(file);
                Files.deleteIfExists(path);
                Files.copy(zipIn, path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you read the entire stream to extract F1. So next time, for F2, `getNextEntry()` returned null. You need to either reopen the zip stream, or, better still, pass a list of files to unzip to your method.